# Symfony5 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
/**
 * Article
 */
class Article
```

inside controller I run:

```
/* 
use App\Entity\Article;
*/

     public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
        {
            try {
                $id = 96;
                $repository = $doctrine->getRepository(Article::class);
                $product = $repository->find($id);
```

As a result I got this: ***An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 't0' in field list***

when I run

```
php bin/console dbal:run-sql 'SELECT * FROM article WHERE id = 96'
```

I got the correct result

It`s strange but i got data from createNativeQuery:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
            ///
        $sql = 'SELECT a.* FROM article a';


        $mappingBuilder = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
        $mappingBuilder->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(Article::class, 'a');

        $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $mappingBuilder);
```

Comment: Having two ORM\Entity annotations is unnecessary.  With attributes it actually generates an error.  Don't have an annotated entity entity handy to test but drop the first one.  The table annotation is unnecessary because the name will default to 'article'  but having one won't hurt.  I suppose you could try removing it.  I assume you have also confirmed that you have a table named article.  No chance of control codes or hidden characters in the name?  And you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: I remove the entity and through php bin/console make:entity  generate a new one - all ok